# Electron-based app flagged as Potentially Unwanted Software by Windows Defender

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder, windows-defender, electron-updater

We have been releasing our Electron-based app for Mac and Windows for the last 2 years, but recently we started having a problem when releasing new versions for Windows. From the recent the new releases are being flagged as "PUA (Potentially Unwanted Software) PUAAdvertising:Win32/CrossRider" by Microsoft Virus & Thread Protection.

We publish our app to an AWS S3 bucket and we use `electron-updater` which detects if newer version was released and then downloads the latest `.exe` and installs it. As I can see the latest version successfully gets downloaded at `\AppData\Local\theappnamehere-updater\pending\theappnamehere.exe`. But it fails to be installed since Windows Defender flags it as `PUAAdvertising`

I had to manually mark the app with "Allow on device" settings, for the warning to be removed.

I also tested to release previous versions since I thought the problem could start happening because of recent changes in the codebase, but it didn't help.

Anyone had a similar problem?

```json
"electron": "23.1.0",
"electron-builder": "23.6.0",
"electron-updater": "^4.3.9"
```

Certificate that we use is from `DigiCert` `.p12` code signing certificate

[image]

Comment: I also created a case with Microsoft Security Intelligence https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission I'm waiting for an Analyst to respond, but no malware was detected by automatic scan process. I assume that whenever I release a new version and `electron-updater` starts the download process, Windows Defender treats that download as an ad. Strange, it has always been working till now, there was no significant change in the codebase or in the release process

Comment: Could you try testing this with a new project? And if it has no problems then start adding parts of your real project to the new one until you find which part triggers the issue. That's the best advice I could think of. I doubt someone will be able to help you without any additional info about your app.

Comment: Hi @zoran404 thanks for the advice. I tried to revert to the versions that we never had problems with and tried to release them with new release number, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Update on the problem that we faced, we have got offical update from Microsoft and the problem of detecting our app as PUA is on their side. **It appeared to be false positive**

**Message from MS representative:**

> Based on the response from WDSI team above, I confirmed that Microsoft
> Defender Antivirus is detecting a false positive alert and blocking
> the genuine application file. Besides, the WDSI team has confirmed
> that the fix is reflected in the latest version of Security
> Intelligent. It is expected that MDAV will not detect
> “YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE.exe” as malicious after updating your endpoint to
> the latest security intelligence version 1.403.2959.0 & above. The
> latest security intelligence update is available for download here:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions. Please assist in
> clearing cache detections, update to the latest security intelligence
> version on the machine facing this issue, and kindly verify.
>
> 1. Open command prompt as administrator and change directory to c:\Program Files\Windows Defender
> 2. Run “MpCmdRun.exe -removedefinitions -dynamicsignatures”
> 3. Run “MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate”

Now we need to inform all of our clients to update their MS security intelligence